# Unable to connect within Internet explorer

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn

Hello I am trying to access a network connection on my local network.
The URL I try was:

```
http://testapp/Aug20/test.com/goLogin.cfm
```

I am able to open it on Mozilla.  But when I try that on Windows IE it leads me to an VPN site.

```
http://guide.opendns.com/?url=testapp%2FAug20%2Ftest.com%2FgoLogin.cfm&servfail
```

Why would that happen and how do I correct it?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413579

Comment: Sir i will close it myself ,if i get the answer

Comment: Ok I will put them in more than one tag

Answer (score 2):

> Why would that happen and how to
>   correct it?

One reason something like that may happen is if you had configured a proxy server in one of your browsers.  When you configure a proxy in a browser usually the proxy server does the DNS lookup, not the local computer.  It appears like you may have IE set to use something else as a proxy, and e proxy server doesn't include your local domain in its DNS search path.

- Verify that you have the proxy settings the same in both browsers
- Add your local name to the exclusion list in the browsers.
- Fix the proxy servers DNS resolver to try lookups with your internal domain.  Or update the /etc/hosts database on the prooxy.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like IE cannot resolve "testapp" to an IP address, so it asks the DNS (in your case, OpenDNS) which doesn't know either, so it redirects IE to an internal "informational" page...
It's strange that Mozilla (Firefox?) do connects to the application, though.. Maybe it has different DNS settings?
Anyway, I'd suggest adding a "testadd" entry to your hosts file and try again.